# Assigning data to an object in a static class

Tags: c#

I have a static class where I want to have a SQLConnectionString be built.

```
public static class SharedUtilities
{
    public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    SharedUtilities()
    {
        connectionString.DataSource = "dx2v";
        connectionString.InitialCatalog = "Q619410";
        connectionString.UserID = "tunnelld";
        connectionString.Password = "david";
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because you can have constructors on static classes. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `static` keyword on the constructor:

```
static SharedUtilities()
```

Because you omitted it, it defaulted to `private`, which is invalid for static classes.

See [Static Constructors (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be with a property that builds the object on demand (creating and filling out the private backing property).

```
public static class SharedUtilities
{
    private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = null;

    public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                {
                    DataSource = "dx2v",
                    InitialCatalog = "Q619410",
                    UserID = "tunnelld",
                    Password = "david",
                };
             }
             return connectionString;
         }
    }
}
```

For reference: [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)